# Flutter Facebook auth through FB application (if installed) not through a WebView

Tags: flutter

I am currently integrating Facebook login through the flutter_facebook_auth package in Flutter.
If I am currently having Facebook application installed on iOS, then login through Facebook in my application it should follow the flowing scenario:

1. If the Facebook application is already installed, when clicking the Facebook login, Facebook application should pop up.
2. Else if we don't have Facebook application, it should divert to a WebView.

It's working this way on Android but on iOS only opens in WebView even if FB application is installed. How to do this for iOS?